# Integration of $x^2\cdot\frac{x\sec^2x+\tan x}{(x\tan x+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate

$$\int x^2\cdot\dfrac{x\sec^2x+\tan x}{(x\tan x+1)^2}dx$$

So what is did is integration by parts taking $x^2$ as $u$ and the other part as $v$ . Now I got to use it again which then eventually leads to (integral of $\dfrac1{x\tan x+1}dx $). Can someone help me?

Comment: $$\dfrac{d(x\tan x+1)}{dx}=?$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

As commented 
start integrating by parts using $$\dfrac{d(x\tan x+1)}{dx}=?$$

to reach at $$\int\dfrac x{x\tan x+1}dx=\int\dfrac{x\cos x}{x\sin x+\cos x}dx$$

Finally utilize $$\dfrac{d(x\sin x+\cos x)}{dx}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

$x \tanx + 1 = t$

$$\int x^2\cdot\dfrac{x\sec^2x+\tan x}{(x\tan x+1)^2}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{x^2}{t^2}dt = x^2* (-1/t) + \int (2x/t)dt$$ (By parts)

$$ = x^2(-1/t) + 2x \ln|t| -2(t \ln|t|-t) + C$$ (By parts again)

Answer (score 0):

Let $u:=x\sin x+\cos x$ so $u^\prime=x\cos x$. You want to integrate$$\begin{align}\frac{x^2(x+\sin x\cos x)}{u^2}&=\frac{x^2(x\cos^2x+u\sin x)}{u^2}\\&=\frac{u^\prime x^2\cos x}{u^2}+\frac{x^2\sin x}{u}\\&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{x^2\cos x}{u}\right)+\frac{(x^2\cos x)^\prime+x^2\sin x}{u}\\&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{x^2\cos x}{u}\right)+\frac{2u^\prime}{u}\\&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{x^2\cos x}{u}+2\ln u\right).\end{align}$$